# How do I change a hidden field's value with jQuery from another input text field?

Tags: jquery, input, hidden

I have four input fields two text and two hidden.

The HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="pie1" class="green" id="pie1" value="Hello"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hPie1" value="green">
<input type="text" name="pie2" class="green" id="pie2" value="Goodbye"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hPie2" value="green">
```

My script code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $('input:text').click(function( ){
  $(this).toggleClass('green red');
 });
})
 </script>
```

Question: How do I change the value of the hidden field to the coherent text field class that is toggled at the same time I click the input box? 
Thanks for any help that you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first fast solution for your problem.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('input:text').click(function( ){
        $(this).toggleClass('green red');
        $(this).next().val($(this).attr('class'));
     });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $('input:text').click(function( ){
  $(this).toggleClass('green red');
  $(this).next().val($(this).attr('class'));
 });
})
```

Should work! Assuming that the hidden inputs always come directly after the text inputs.

Comment: I get the value from the text input and not the current toggled class name. It's not the value from the text input I want. It's the class. That's why I find it so hard.

Comment: So you want to know $(this).attr('class')..? See updated answer.

Comment: Yeah Kasihasi answered it well. Thanks for all help

Answer (score 0):

after `$(this).toggleClass('green red');

add `$('input[name="h' + $(this).name() + '"]').val($(this).val())`

note - =`$(this).name()` element may have incorrect syntax, but that's the idea.

Comment: Hey thx for replying. Though I get the script error "$(this).name is not a function" .